# Mongodb find() don't work

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack, mean, database

Why dosen't `db.find` work? The `console.log` gets undefined...

```
 var course = (db.courses.find({ _id: mongo.helper.toObjectID(param.course)}));
 console.log(course.body)
```

Comment: It's because [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) in mongo shell returns a cursor to the documents that match the query criteria. Use [`findOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#db.collection.findOne) instead to return the matching document.

Comment: Tried ´db.courses.findOne(({ _id: mongo.helper.toObjectID(param.course)}))´but it still returns undefiend @chridam

Comment: Use a callback function to get the returned document. The example I gave above is for mongo shell. in Node.js you will need a callback i.e. `db.courses.findOne({ _id: mongo.helper.toObjectID(param.course)}, function (err, course) { console.log(course); })`

Comment: Thanks for the help, that worked! @chridam

Comment: Run your query: var course = db.courses.findOne({ _id: mongo.helper.toObjectID(param.course)}); and check course.count(). Check for the count to be greater than zero.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are trying use `Selects documents in a collection and returns a cursor to the selected documents.`, so you can't use the way you are trying to use it.

You need to use a `callback()` to get the records matching the query.

The below code will give result in an array format :-

```
db.courses.findOne({ _id: mongo.helper.toObjectID(param.course)}).toArray(function(err, result)
{
    console.log(result[0]); // will give you the matched record.
})
```

Comment: If the query is going to return a single document (since it's querying on the `_id` field), you might as well use the `fineOne()` method which will return the document.

Comment: @chridam Ok. Didn't think of that. Thanks for pointing out. Will update my answer.